# how to sort out a nested list in R

Tags: r, list, sorting, nested

The original data was a simple list named "data" like this

```
[1] "score: 10 / review 1 / ID 1
[2] "score: 9 / review 2 / ID 2
[3] "score: 8 / review 3 / ID 3
----
[30] "score: 7 / review 30 / ID&DATE: 30
```

In order to sort out scores reviews and ID&DATEs separately,
I first made it a matrix, and then split them by "/" using str_split "stringr"

so the whole process went like this.

```
a1 <- readLines("data.txt")
a2 <- t(a1)   # Matrix 
a3 <- t(a2)   # reversing rows and columns
b1 <- str_split(a,"/")
```

here is the problem 
b1 came out as a nested list like this.

```
[[1]]
[1] "score: 10"
[2] "review 1"
[3] "ID 1"

[[2]]
[1] "score: 9"
[2] "review 2"
[3] "ID 2"

[[3]]
[1] "score: 8"
[2] "review 3"
[3] "ID 3"

------

[[30]]
[1] "score: 7"
[2] "review 30"
[3] "ID 30"
```

I want to extract the values of [[1]][1], [[2]][1], [[3]][1], ... [[30]][1], [[n]][2], and [[n]][3] SEPARATELY, and make each one of them a dataframe.

Any clues?

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(head(a1))`.

Comment: It seems that "b1" is just a "list" with `length == 3` atomic elements; wrapping `.mapply(c, b1, NULL)` with `as.data.frame` should work

Answer (score 0):

The following would work for a particular type of nested list that looks like your data. Without a reproducible example, I don't know for sure:

```
# create nested list
temp <- list(a=c(list("score: 10"), "review 1", "ID 1"), 
         b=c("score: 9", "review 2", "ID 2"),
         c=c("score: 8", "review 3","ID 3"))

# create data frame from this list
df <- data.frame(score=unlist(sapply(temp, function(i) i[1])),
                 review=unlist(sapply(temp, function(i) i[2])),
                 ID=unlist(sapply(temp, function(i) i[3])))
```

I use `sapply` to pull out elements from each list item. Then, `unlist` is applied to the output so that it becomes a vector.  All of this out put is wrapped in a data.frame. Note that you can rearrange the output so that the variables are arranged differently.

An even cleaner method, mentioned by @parfait, uses `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
# construct data.frame, rbinding each list item
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, temp))
# add the desired names
names(df) <- c('score', 'review', 'ID')
```

Comment: Consider: `df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, temp)) ; names(df) <- c('score', 'review', 'ID')`

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. That looks a lot cleaner. I'll add it.